# Taking quotients over isometric groups and determining the cokernel of transformations

Tags: quotient-group, free-modules, smith-normal-form

We know that given group $A$ and subgroups $B_1,B_2$ such that $B_1\cong B_2$, it is not necessary that $A/B_1\cong A/B_2$.
Now take for instance the following transformation $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^3$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3
\\
4 & 5 & 6
\\
7 & 8 & 9
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Because column and row operations preserve isometry, we can reduce it to the normal smith form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0
\\
0 & 3 & 0
\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Similarly to vector spaces, this allows us to determine the kernel and the image:
$\mathrm{Im} (\varphi)\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus3\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}^2$.
Intuitively I know that the cokernel is supposed to be $\mathbb{Z}^3/\mathbb{Z}\oplus3\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}/3\oplus\mathbb{Z}$
and not
$\mathbb{Z}^3/\mathbb{Z}^2=\mathbb{Z}$, but I don't understand why is it true mathematically.
I understand that the normal smith form is supposed to represent in some way what the group structure 'actually' is. But haven't we only stated that it preserves the group's isometry?